# How do I enter edit mode every time I use the transform tool icon

Tags: python, tools

I have a small question , how do I enter the edit mode every time I click on the transform tool.

my current strategy is to delete the actual transform tool from the toolbar (already done that) and then make my own tool that fully implement the transform tool but enter the edit mode at the beginning (couldn't do that).

Comment: Which transform tool? To switch between Object and Edit mode just press the Tab key or hit Ctrl-Tab  to bring up the pie menu.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but I want to code it to work that way .. I am building my own toolbar for blender.

Comment: Ah ok. No idea in that case. I assume you're using python which I don't use.